# How to get my like button in django to work?

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to get my like button to work on my website. You can make "tweets" on my website, but users are not able to like the post. I already have the front end set up with ajax. that works perfect. The problem lies in my views.

Here is my models

```
    class Tweet(models.Model):
    tweet_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tweet_message = models.TextField()
    tweet_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tweet_like_counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tweet_picture = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet_message


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(Tweet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet.tweet_message

class Disike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(Tweet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet.tweet_message


class TweetComment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    tweetcomment = models.ForeignKey(Tweet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tweetcomments')
    tweetcommentauthor = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tweetcommentmessage = models.TextField()
    tweetcommentcomment_date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweetcommentmessage
```

Here is my view

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def like(request, pk):


    currentTweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet,pk=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    like = Like.objects.create(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)
    like_queryset = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)
    dislike_queryset = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)






    if like_queryset.exists():
        Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user).delete()
        dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
        currentTweet.save()

    if  dislike_queryset.exists():
        Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user).delete()
        dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
        currentTweet.save()





    return JsonResponse({
        'like_counter': currentTweet.tweet_like_counter


    })




@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def dislike(request, pk):
    currentTweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet, pk=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    dislike = Disike.objects.create(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)
    like_queryset = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)
    dislike_queryset = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)


    if dislike_queryset.exists():
        Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user).delete()
        dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
        currentTweet.save()

    if like_queryset.exists():
        Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user).delete()
        dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
        currentTweet.save()








    return JsonResponse({
        'like_counter':  currentTweet.tweet_like_counter

    })
```

I dont know what else to do. When i run this code, i get no errors, but when i click the like button, no like object is made...

BUT when i use this code in the view.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def like(request, pk):


    currentTweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet,pk=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    like = Like.objects.create(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)
    like_queryset = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)
    dislike_queryset = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)











    return JsonResponse({
        'like_counter': currentTweet.tweet_like_counter


    })




@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def dislike(request, pk):
    currentTweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet, pk=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    dislike = Disike.objects.create(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)
    like_queryset = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)
    dislike_queryset = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)










    return JsonResponse({
        'like_counter':  currentTweet.tweet_like_counter

    })
```

A like is created, but then users will be able to continue liking the same post. I been stuck on this for about a day or two. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make the check first if like object exists before creating a new like object. Like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def like(request, pk):
    currentTweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet,pk=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    like_queryset = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)

    if not like_queryset.exists():
        like = Like.objects.create(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)
        dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
        currentTweet.save()

    return JsonResponse({
        'like_counter': currentTweet.tweet_like_counter
    })
```

#### A Small Optimization

A small edit on the answer is, you don't need to save the like counter is DB. You can create a Property method in `Tweet` model to get the like counter. For example:

```
class Tweet(...):
     ...  # rest of the code

    @property
    def tweet_like_counter(self):
       likes = self.like_set.all().count()
       dislikes = self.like_set.all().count()
       return likes - dislikes
```

In this way, you don't need to store the like counter in DB, and like counts will be calculated dynamically. Using that property method, you can update the view like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def like(request, pk):
    currentTweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet,pk=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    like_queryset = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)

    if not like_queryset.exists():
        like = Like.objects.create(tweet=currentTweet, user=user)

    return JsonResponse({
        'like_counter': currentTweet.tweet_like_counter
    })
```

Comment: any chance you can help me with the ajax? i thought i had it correct. but when i add more than one post. It seems to be bugging out. with one post it works fine.

Comment: maybe you can ask a new question on this :) I am not that good with ajax unfortunately.

Comment: hey, i fixed the ajax myself, but here is the last problem i see. When i add more than one post. users can like more than one time for some reason. When its just one post, they can only like and dislike one time. But when its two post, they can like and dislike two times. when its three post. they can like and dislike three times. Why is that?

Comment: I am not sure from ajax, but when there is two posts, then user can comment in both of them. I am not sure how you are maintaining relation between two tweets, you can ensure that user can comment on only parent post.